# Maximizing the coverage of a rectangle in an array

Tags: computer-science

I have a task as follows:

Input:

`0 0 1 0 0 1 0
 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
 0 0 1 0 0 1 0`

where `0`s denote Apple trees and `1`s denote Banana trees

Alex wants to keep all the Apple trees while Beret wants to keep the Banana trees.
The cost of transferring the ownership of a tree is $1.

Find the best starting rectangle such that the cost is as low as possible.

The solution for this example is as follows:
[image: solution]

Output: $6 (to transfer the ownership of the 6 trees)

Maximum execution time is 1.0s with input of
    1 < n < 150 and 2 < m < 5, 000
where `n` and `m` is the orchard's size

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are particular requirements concerning the running time or the overall approach, you can use a rather simple solution: For each possible rectangle check how many trees have to be moved. This can be done with 4 nested `for` loops and some utility methods.

Here is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (I did not test it thoroughly, but it should show the general approach)

```
public class OptimizeRectangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int array[][] =
        {
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, 
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        };
        optimize(array);
    }

    private static void optimize(int array[][])
    {
        int rows = array.length;
        int cols = array[0].length;
        int ones = count(array, 0, 0, rows, cols, 1);
        int bestR0 = 0;
        int bestC0 = 0;
        int bestR1 = 0;
        int bestC1 = 0;
        int minToMove = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int r0=0; r0<rows; r0++)
        {
            for (int c0=0; c0<cols; c0++)
            {
                for (int r1=r0+1; r1<=rows; r1++)
                {
                    for (int c1=c0+1; c1<=cols; c1++)
                    {
                        int zerosInRect = count(array, r0, c0, r1, c1, 0);
                        int onesInRect = count(array, r0, c0, r1, c1, 1);
                        int toMove = 
                            (ones - onesInRect) + zerosInRect;
                        if (toMove < minToMove)
                        {
                            minToMove = toMove;
                            bestR0 = r0;
                            bestC0 = c0;
                            bestR1 = r1;
                            bestC1 = c1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Input");
        System.out.println(toString(array));

        int a[][] = copy(array);
        set(a, bestR0, bestC0, bestR1, bestC1, -1);
        System.out.println("Result");
        System.out.println(toString(a));
    }

    private static String toString(int array[][])
    {
        int rows = array.length;
        int cols = array[0].length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int r=0; r<rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<cols; c++)
            {
                if (array[r][c] >= 0)
                {
                    sb.append(array[r][c]+" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.append("  ");
                }
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static int[][] copy(int array[][])
    {
        int result[][] = new int[array.length][];
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = array[i].clone();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void set(int array[][], 
        int r0, int c0, int r1, int c1, int value)
    {
        for (int r=r0; r<r1; r++)
        {
            for (int c=c0; c<c1; c++)
            {
                array[r][c] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private static int count(int array[][], 
        int r0, int c0, int r1, int c1, int value)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int r=r0; r<r1; r++)
        {
            for (int c=c0; c<c1; c++)
            {
                if (array[r][c] == value)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: hi, is there any faster methods? this solution exceeded the max. execution time of 1.0s for bigger inputs :/

Comment: @user3368484 Something like this should already be stated in the question! You can use a dynamic programming approach, but I won't do your homework (beyond what I've already done...)

Comment: sry ive updated the qn. could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @user3368484 I already mentioned *dynamic programming*. The basic idea is: For each array entry, you compute the number of "ones" and the number of "zeros" that is in the lower right sub-array of the entry. Then, given two entries, you can subtract these numbers, and immediately receive the number of ones and zeros that are in the rectangle that is defined by these entries (and you don't have to *count* the ones and zeros any more). This is just a first thought, however. Thinking further is **your** task.